# Hollow histogram or binning for geom_step

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggproto

I would like to draw a hollow histogram that has no vertical bars drawn inside of it, but just an outline. I couldn't find any way to do it with `geom_histogram`. The `geom_step`+`stat_bin` combination seemed like it could do the job. However, the bins of `geom_step`+`stat_bin` are shifted by a half bin either to the right or to the left, depending on the step's `direction=` parameter value. It seems like it is doing its "steps" WRT bin centers. Is there any way to change this behavior so it would do the "steps" at bin edges?

Here's an illustration:

```
d <- data.frame(x=rnorm(1000))
qplot(x, data=d, geom="histogram",
      breaks=seq(-4,4,by=.5), color=I("red"), fill = I("transparent")) +
geom_step(stat="bin", breaks=seq(-4,4,by=.5), color="black", direction="vh")
```

[image]

Comment: there now is `direction = "mid"` which does just that (see [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63710110/1870254))

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I propose making a new Geom like so:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(proto)

geom_stephist <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat="bin", position="identity", ...) {
  GeomStepHist$new(mapping=mapping, data=data, stat=stat, position=position, ...)
}

GeomStepHist <- proto(ggplot2:::Geom, {
  objname <- "stephist"

  default_stat <- function(.) StatBin
  default_aes <- function(.) aes(colour="black", size=0.5, linetype=1, alpha = NA)

  reparameterise <- function(., df, params) {
    transform(df,
              ymin = pmin(y, 0), ymax = pmax(y, 0),
              xmin = x - width / 2, xmax = x + width / 2, width = NULL
    )
  }

  draw <- function(., data, scales, coordinates, ...) {
    data <- as.data.frame(data)[order(data$x), ]

    n <- nrow(data)
    i <- rep(1:n, each=2)
    newdata <- rbind(
      transform(data[1, ], x=xmin, y=0),
      transform(data[i, ], x=c(rbind(data$xmin, data$xmax))),
      transform(data[n, ], x=xmax, y=0)
    )
    rownames(newdata) <- NULL

    GeomPath$draw(newdata, scales, coordinates, ...)
  }
  guide_geom <- function(.) "path"
})
```

This also works for non-uniform breaks. To illustrate the usage:

```
d <- data.frame(x=runif(1000, -5, 5))
ggplot(d, aes(x)) +
  geom_histogram(breaks=seq(-4,4,by=.5), color="red", fill=NA) +
  geom_stephist(breaks=seq(-4,4,by=.5), color="black")
```

[image: plot]

Comment: That's a nice seamless hack! It even allows the usual simple faceting and default binning. 

But the most natural solution would probably be to add a parameter to geom_histogram for disabling inner vertical bars.

Comment: @VadimKhotilovich The parameter option is difficult, I think, because `geom_histogram` is built about `stat_bin` and `geom_bar` and `geom_bar` isn't really set up to selectively include/exclude only portions of its vertical edges.

Comment: @joran: such technical difficulties cannot overturn the fact that "a histogram is not a bar chart" (it's a quote straight from "The Grammar of Graphics" book). Generally speaking, histograms represent distributions and bar charts are for comparing categories. While ggplot2 implements a histogram as a trivial alias over bar+bin, it doesn't have to stay that way. And I would add that a histogram is not a step chart either.

Comment: @VadimKhotilovich There's no need to lecture me, I'm well aware of all that. I was simply explaining why such a change might be more work than is feasible given limited developer time, that's all.

Comment: @joran: thanks for clarifying. It's sometimes hard to guess people's intentions from small posts... If I would ever have time to dig deeper into the ggplot2 source and proto, I would contribute to improving the histogram. Some things in it were bugging me for a while.

Comment: @VadimKhotilovich No problem. In fact, I should apologize, I wrote that comment while under the cloud of some extremely irritating things going on offline and let that influence me too much.

Comment: I used to rely on geom_stephist very much but it doesn't work anymore with ggproto of ggplot2's v2 (aka ggplot2_2.0.0). It would be really helpful if someone could use this as an example to illustrate creating new gems in ggplot2_2.0.0 Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

This isn't ideal, but it's the best I can come up with:

```
h <- hist(d$x,breaks=seq(-4,4,by=.5))
d1 <- data.frame(x = h$breaks,y = c(h$counts,NA))

ggplot() + 
    geom_histogram(data = d,aes(x = x),breaks = seq(-4,4,by=.5),
                                 color = "red",fill = "transparent") + 
    geom_step(data = d1,aes(x = x,y = y),stat = "identity")
```

[image]

Comment: @Henrik I like all three of these solutions, frankly.

Answer (score 11):

Yet another one. Use `ggplot_build` to build a plot object of the histogram for rendering. From this object `x` and `y` values are extracted, to be used for `geom_step`. Use `by` to offset `x` values.

```
by <- 0.5
p1 <- ggplot(data = d, aes(x = x)) +
  geom_histogram(breaks = seq(from = -4, to = 4, by = by),
                 color = "red", fill = "transparent")

df <- ggplot_build(p1)$data[[1]][ , c("x", "y")]

p1 +
  geom_step(data = df, aes(x = x - by/2, y = y))
```

[image]

**Edit** following comment from @Vadim Khotilovich (Thanks!)

The `xmin` from the plot object can be used instead (-> no need for offset adjustment)

```
df <- ggplot_build(p1)$data[[1]][ , c("xmin", "y")]

p1 +
  geom_step(data = df, aes(x = xmin, y = y))
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to ggplot_build. It provides lots of potentially useful data! In this particular case though, I would subset it by [ , c("xmin", "y")] to get the lower edges directly.

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, when you run out of 'normal' `ggplot` options, it can be quite fruitful to walk the `ggplot_build` path. You can also manipulate the data within the plot object and then plot it using `grid` functions.

Answer (score 7):

An alternative, also less than ideal:

```
qplot(x, data=d, geom="histogram", breaks=seq(-4,4,by=.5), color=I("red"), fill = I("transparent")) +
  stat_summary(aes(x=round(x * 2 - .5) / 2, y=1), fun.y=length, geom="step")
```

Missing some bins that you can probably add back if you mess around a bit.  Only (somewhat meaningless) advantage is it is more in `ggplot` than @Joran's answer, though even that is debatable.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I answer my own comment earlier today: here is a modified version of @RosenMatev's answer updated for the v2 (ggplot2_2.0.0) using ggproto:

```
GeomStepHist <- ggproto("GeomStepHist", GeomPath,
                        required_aes = c("x"),

                        draw_panel = function(data, panel_scales, coord, direction) {
                          data <- as.data.frame(data)[order(data$x), ]

                          n <- nrow(data)
                          i <- rep(1:n, each=2)
                          newdata <- rbind(
                            transform(data[1, ], x=x - width/2, y=0),
                            transform(data[i, ], x=c(rbind(data$x-data$width/2, data$x+data$width/2))),
                            transform(data[n, ], x=x + width/2, y=0)
                          )
                          rownames(newdata) <- NULL

                          GeomPath$draw_panel(newdata, panel_scales, coord)
                        }
)


geom_step_hist <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "bin",
                           direction = "hv", position = "stack", na.rm = FALSE, 
                           show.legend = NA, inherit.aes = TRUE, ...) {
  layer(
    data = data,
    mapping = mapping,
    stat = stat,
    geom = GeomStepHist,
    position = position,
    show.legend = show.legend,
    inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = list(
      direction = direction,
      na.rm = na.rm,
      ...
    )
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**TLDR: use `geom_step(..., direction = "mid")`**

This has become much easier since Daniel Mastropietro and Dewey Dunnington [implemented](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/pull/3435) the "mid" as an additional option for the `direction` argument of `geom_step` for ggplot2 v3.3.0:

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)
d <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1000))
ggplot(d, aes(x)) + 
  geom_histogram(breaks = seq(-4, 4, by=.5), color="red", fill = "transparent") +
  geom_step(stat="bin", breaks=seq(-4, 4, by=.5), color = "black", direction = "mid")
```

[image]

Below, for reference, the code from the question formatted like above answer:

```r
ggplot(d, aes(x)) + 
  geom_histogram(breaks = seq(-4, 4, by=.5), color = "red", fill = "transparent") +
  geom_step(stat="bin", breaks = seq(-4, 4, by=.5), color = "black", direction = "vh")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-09-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

a simple way to do something similar to @Rosen Matev (that does not work with ggplot2_2.0.0 as mentioned by @julou), I would just
1) calculate manually the value of the bins (using a small function as shown below)
2) use geom_step()
Hope this helps !

```
geom_step_hist<- function(d,binw){
  dd=NULL
  bin=min(d$y) # this enables having a first value that is = 0 (to have the left vertical bar of the plot when using geom_step)
  max=max(d$y)+binw*2 # this enables having a last value that is = 0 (to have the right vertical bar of the plot when using geom_step)
  xx=NULL
  yy=NULL
  while(bin<=max){
    n=length(temp$y[which(temp$y<bin & temp$y>=(bin-binw))])
    yy=c(yy,n)
    xx=c(xx,bin-binw)
    bin=bin+binw
    rm(n)
  }
  dd=data.frame(xx,yy)
  return(dd)
}
hist=ggplot(dd,aes(x=xx,y=yy))+
geom_step()
```